# Cerrar una ventana externa a mi página

Tags: javascript, angular, chrome

no encuentro por ningún sitio una manera para cerrar una ventana del navegador específica que no sea la actual y que no se haya abierto desde nuestra aplicación/web.

Para que lo entiendan mejor, yo programo en Angular, y digamos que si desde mi aplicación hiciera lo siguiente:

```
abrirVentana() {
    this.myWindow = window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
}

cerrarVentana() {
    this.myWindow.close();
}
```

Si pulso sobre un botón con el primer método y luego sobre otro con el segundo, cierro la nueva ventana que abrí.

Lo que quiero saber es si existe alguna manera de cerrar, siguiendo la página de ejemplo, una ventana de `www.google.com` pero que haya abierto a mano y no desde mi aplicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo es posible si la pagina ha sido abierta desde nuestra aplicación o pagina web, utilizando javascript te dejo un enlace para que comprendas esta cuestión.

http://lineadecodigo.com/javascript/cerrar-una-ventana-con-javascript/

Comment: Vale, entonces no es posible. Muchas gracias por la documentación :)